# How can I change the default font size that is set on charts in a PowerPoint template?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, charts, xml

As the title says I'm interested in knowing how I can change the default font size that is set on charts in a specific PowerPoint template. 
I'm not interested in using chart-templates for this, since I only want the user to have to use the PowerPoint-template, and not rely on any chart-templates.

I know you can change the default font size on that is set on tables via XML, but I can't find any place in the XML that shows where the default font size for charts is set.

Does anyone know if this could be done via XML?